# Unable to add more links to nav

Tags: html, responsive-design, nav

I have downloaded the HTML5 template from http://html5up.net/prologue. The template is responsive. The default template comes with 4 items on the `nav` and looks like this:
[image]

I want to add more items to the `nav`. So I modified `nav` by adding two lines of code for `ff` and `gg`:

```
<nav id="nav">                          
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#top" id="top-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-home">Intro</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-th">Portfolio</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" id="about-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-user">About Me</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" id="contact-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-envelope">Contact</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#ff" id="contact-link2" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-envelope">ff</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#gg" id="contact-link3" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-envelope">gg</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But now when I scroll the `nav` isn't updated properly. It works upto 4 items in the nav(as was the default), but not anything beyond 4. See example below:

[image]

How do I fix this? There's nothing much in the css for nav to change/impact.

**EDIT**

I'm adding the code that I have added into the `body` of the page.

```
<!-- Contact (given in the template) -->
<section id="contact" class="four">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
        </header>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- I've added the two sections below -->
<section id="ff" class="five">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
        </header>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="gg" class="six">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
        </header>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sections where you have placed the actual content for each nav item must have the same `id` values as what you have specified in `href` attribute of each anchor. You have kept the `id="contact"` for the new two sections too that is causing the issue.

For the new two sections added your section tags should be like:

```
<section id="ff" class="five">
```

and

```
<section id="gg" class="six">
```

I have downloaded the template and tested it out, Here is one more thing that you will have to follow, on the links in navbar, your anchors **ids** will match this patter *href_value-link*, so your nav code should be:

```
<nav id="nav">                          
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#top" id="top-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-home">Intro</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-th">Portfolio</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" id="about-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-user">About Me</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" id="contact-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-envelope">Contact</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#ff" id="ff-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-envelope">ff</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#gg" id="gg-link" class="skel-layers-ignoreHref"><span class="icon fa-envelope">gg</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The heading is same for the last three i.e., contact. However, the `id` are not the same. There is a mistake in your answer as well that is `id` must be equal to `href` of the nav i.e., `<section id=ff class="five"`.

Comment: I have updated my answer above, please see the updated nav code.

Answer (score 0):

That call fairy in section page
Try to find this code in accordance with the template and add you planted on the left sidebar

```
<section id="contact" class="four">

#contact  to call id="contact"
```

Comment: http://188.166.98.250/index.html is original ... http://188.166.98.250/index2.html is the modified one. Thanks!